# How to make cakephp 3 url ready for marketing?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I am new for cakephp. I am trying to rewrite the url to make it SEO friendly.

I have create module in cakephp3 for cms page.

Page Table - url field would like to use as "about-us"

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `detail` text NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=14 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Current URL (working)-
https://example.com/pages/view/8

I want to make this like below.
https://example.com/about-us

Please suggest.

Comment: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

In your cakephp3 folder, there is a file "routes.php" in \config.

[image]

Open the "routes.php" and use:

```
use Cake\Routing\Router;

// Using the scoped route builder.
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
    $routes->connect('/about-us', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'view', 8]);
});

// Or using the static method.
Router::connect('/about-us', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'view', 8]);
```

Comment: i got your suggesting good. could you let me know how i can make it dynamic as i can not write for 100 of pages

Answer (score 0):

in side route::

```
Router::scope('/', function ($routes) {
$routes->connect('/:title', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' =>  'home'],['pass' => ['title']]);
});
```

//in PagesController

```
public function home($title=NULL){ 
        echo $title;//title = 'yogendra'
}
```

browser url:: http://localhost/project-name/yogendra
you can compare title with you DB table and display page dynamically
Hope you fixed the issue. :)